# if isset no valida correctamente $_FILES (PHP)

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario con muchos campos `type="text"` y un campo `type=file` que permite cargar multiples archivos (el cual no es obligatorio), la parte que me está causando una validación errónea es el de `file`.

Coloco el **código**:

```
         if(isset($_FILES['acta_baja']['tmp_name'])){
            $num_files = count($_FILES['acta_baja']['tmp_name']);

            $permitidos = array("application/pdf"");     
            $limite_kb = 1000000;

            for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++){

              if(in_array($_FILES["acta_baja"]["type"][$i], $permitidos) && $_FILES["acta_baja"]["size"][$i] <= $limite_kb * 1024){

                $ruta = '../../files/actas_baja/enfriadores/'.$idnext_solicitud.'/';

                if(!file_exists($ruta)){
                   mkdir($ruta);
                }

                $ruta2 = '../../files/actas_baja/enfriadores/'.$idnext_solicitud.'/'.$id_enfriador.'/';

                if(!file_exists($ruta2)){
                   mkdir($ruta2);
                }

                $acta_baja = $ruta2.$_FILES["acta_baja"]["name"][$i];

                if(!file_exists($acta_baja)){

                  $resultado1 = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["acta_baja"]["tmp_name"][$i], $acta_baja);

                } else{

                  $acta_bajaErr= "El archivo ya existe";
                  $valid = false;
                }
              } else{
                $acta_bajaErr= "Formato no valido o el archivo sobrepasa el tamaño permitido.";
                $valid= false;
              }
            }   
          }
```

Ocurre que siempre entra a `if(isset($_FILES['acta_baja']['tmp_name']))` probé también con `!empty` y sigue igual. Aunque no se haya seleccionado ningún archivo  me manda el mensaje:

> Formato no valido o el archivo sobrepasa el tamaño permitido

Como si estuviera validando algún archivo. Lo que quiero lograr es que cuando el usuario no cargue ningún archivo se omita el código y solo guarde la información que resta del formulario.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isset()` solo te comprueba si está definida la variable, en este caso puedes usar `is_uploaded_file`:

```
 if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['acta_baja']['tmp_name'])){
     //viene un archivo
 }
```

Debes asegurarte que tu formulario sea `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Ya lo probé también así y ocurre lo mismo, lo agregué a mi pregunta ya que fue un detalle que olvidé comentar

Comment: verifica que tu formulario sea `enctype="multipart/form-data" `

Comment: @IndiraRivas edite mi respuesta espero te sirva

Comment: Es correcto, así está

Comment: @IndiraRivas mira la edicion usando is_uploaded_file